# Angular ng-repeat on-filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Does angular have a onfilter method or onquery as you type to query through results:

for example:

```
<input type='text' ng-model='query'>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td># of Enrollments</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat='c in courses | filter:query' onfilter='someStuff()'>
        <td>{{c.name}}</td>
        <td>{{c.enrollmentLength}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

when I type in the input text the letter "a", I want it to call the someStuff() function.

Comment: Why not just do `<input type='text' ng-model='query' ng-change="someStuff()">`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you do this is with a watch inside your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('query', function(newval) {
   // this will fire when query is changed
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter can [call a function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) instead of using an expression. Here's an example:

```
$scope.processQuery = function(course) {
  // do some processing
};


<input type='text' ng-model='query'>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td># of Enrollments</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat='c in courses | filter:processQuery'>
        <td>{{c.name}}</td>
        <td>{{c.enrollmentLength}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```